# Aggregate pandas rows and store as dicts or other suitable data types

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, pandas-groupby

I have pandas DataFrame that I am trying to aggregate and store the select columns as `dicts`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'id': [1, 1, 2],
                   'lat': [37.7825, 37.7825, 37.7836],
                   'lon': [-122.4148, -122.4148, -122.4127],
                   'b': [1, 2, 1],
                   'r': [1000, 1300, 1100],
                   's': [650, 720, 600]
                 })
```

I'd like to aggregate the DataFrame such that every unique combination of `b`, `r` and `s` are stored as collections, a `list of dicts` in one column.

Account for any edge cases such as `NaNs` in `b`, `r` or `s`. If `NaNs`, then do not store them as dicts.

Expected output:

```
id lat      lon        new

1  37.7825  -122.4148  [{'b': 1, 'r': 1000, 's': 650}, {'b': 2, 'r': 1300, 's': 720}]
2  37.7836  -122.4127  [{'b': 1, 'r': 1100, 's': 600}]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can call `to_dict` as "records" in `groupby.apply`:

```py
out = df.groupby(['id','lat','lon'])[['b','r','s']].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('records')).reset_index(name='new')
```

Output:

```py
   id      lat       lon                                                             new
0   1  37.7825 -122.4148  [{'b': 1, 'r': 1000, 's': 650}, {'b': 2, 'r': 1300, 's': 720}]
1   2  37.7836 -122.4127                                 [{'b': 1, 'r': 1100, 's': 600}]
```